Creating Independent Parent Attributes in Pydantic
I have an activity class like this:
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra, Field

class Activity(BaseModel, extra=Extra.ignore, frozen=True):
    """Stores ship specific information."""

    id: ActivityId
    owner: Optional[str] = Field(None, min_length=2, max_length=2)
    ship_number: Optional[int] = None
    origin: str = Field(min_length=3, max_length=3)
    origin_sub_location: Optional[str] = None
    destination: str = Field(min_length=3, max_length=3)
    destination_sub_location: Optional[str] = None
    start_time: datetime
    end_time: datetime

I then want to inherit the class to create another activity (Lake) with the inheritance done ad hoc but with one new field is_overnight that is unique to a Lake Activity. Is there a cleaner way of doing it than this?
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Any, Optional

from pydantic import PrivateAttr

class Lake(Activity):
    _is_overnight: bool = PrivateAttr(False)

    def __init__(
        self,
        start_time: datetime,
        location: str,
        is_overnight: bool,
        sub_location: Optional[str] = None,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ):
        # Automatically set end_time, origin, and destination to the same as start_time and location
        super().__init__(
            start_time=start_time,
            end_time=start_time,  # same as start_time for lakes
            origin=location,
            destination=location,
            origin_sub_location=sub_location,
            destination_sub_location=sub_location,
            cancelled=False,
            id=f"LAKE_{location}{sub_location}_{start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}",
            **kwargs,
        )
        self._is_overnight = is_overnight

    @property
    def is_overnight(self) -> bool:
        return self._is_overnight


Defining __init__ in a pydantic model seems intuitively wrong. If you need to add new field, do this:
class Lake2(Activity):
    _is_overnight: bool = PrivateAttr(default=False)

If you want to generate id from fields of the current instance of model, use
model_post_init:
class Lake2(Activity):
    _is_overnight: bool = PrivateAttr(default=False)

    def model_post_init(self, __context):
        self.id = (
            f"LAKE_{self.destination}{self.origin_sub_location}_"
            f"{self.start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}"
        )

If you want to add a new field instead of an old one e. g. location -> destination, you couldn't. Just define it in descriptors (but model would contain both attributes):
class Lake2(Activity):
    _is_overnight: bool = PrivateAttr(default=False)
    location: str = Field(min_length=3, max_length=3)

I would not recommend to pass it like an __init__ argument. And if your child id field does not match ActivityId type, you also should redefine it:
class Lake2(Activity):
    _is_overnight: bool = PrivateAttr(default=False)
    id: str

